# Qt gdal Error: ‘Open’ is not a member of ‘OGRSFDriverRegistrar’

Tags: qt, gdal

I am working on a Qt project with gdal libraries.

Qt5.9.1. Ubuntu 16.10 LTS.

I am getting an error and I have no clue what is going wrong.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include "ogrsf_frmts.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    OGRRegisterAll();
    OGRDataSource *source;

    source = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open( <path to s57 file>, FALSE );
    if( source == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Open failed.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
main.cpp:11: error: 
'Open' is not a member of 'OGRSFDriverRegistrar';

source = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open( <path to s57 chart file>, FALSE );
```

Can anybody please help me in resolving the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class **OGRSFDriverRegistrar** is marked as a Legacy class and as such is deprecated.

The [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716160300/http://www.gdal.org:80/classOGRSFDriverRegistrar.html#details) suggest using [GDALDriverManager()](https://web.archive.org/web/20180717183020/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALDriverManager.html) as quoted here:

> Use GDALDriverManager in your new code ! This class may be removed in
> a later release.

Which version of GDAL are you using? It could be that **OGRSFDriverRegistrar** is already removed.

Anyway removed or not, I suggest you should try updating your code with GDALDriverManager.

**EDIT: Added example.**

```
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h" // for CPLMalloc()
int main()
{
    GDALDataset  *poDataset;
    GDALAllRegister();
    poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen( pszFilename, GA_ReadOnly );
    if( poDataset == NULL )
    {
        ...;
    }
}
```

Taken from GDAL API [tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html).

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I was not getting where to start from. Took some code available online and started with it. Thanks Mr. Peter. But this method is unable to open a .000 s57 enc file. Says not recognised file format. Will look for this now.

Comment: Found a working solution as of now to open the file successfully.

    _dataSet = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpenEx("US2EC03M.000",GDAL_OF_VECTOR,NULL,NULL,NULL);_

Comment: The [API tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) is a great start point.

Comment: Landed on the same page searching for the solutions. Thanks a lot. :-) but this [OGR tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html)  is exactly that gave me the solution

Answer (score 0):

Found the [OGR Tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html). the functions are explained with example here. Initial help was given by @Petar. On further exploring the website i found the exact methods to work upon.

```
GDALDataset *dataSet;
GDALAllRegister();
dataSet = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpenEx("ENCFILE.000",GDAL_OF_VECTOR,NULL,NULL,NULL);
if(dataSet == NULL)
{
    printf( "Open failed.\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}
else
{
    printf( "SUCCESS.\n" );
}
```